# JavaScript: transform a string to json with some rules

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to write a function which can transform the following data (input string) to a json.

data:

```
AA,BB
,CC
,,DD
,EE
```

JSON:

```
{
  "AA": [
    {
      "BB": []
    },
    {
      "CC": [
        {
          "DD": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "EE": []
    }
  ]
}
```

AA, BB, CC ... can any string and the data is input as a string.

I write a part of the function (see the following codes) and have no more good idea.

```
function str2json(str) {
  var lines = str.split("\n");
  var arr = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
  {
    var objs = lines[i].split(",");
    arr.push(objs);
  }
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    for (let j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
    {
      if(arr[i][j].length === 0)
      {
        arr[i][j] = arr[i-1][j];
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // TODO
}
```

I just transform the data into an array then add right data into null, the result is:

```
AA,BB
AA,CC
AA,CC,EE
AA,FF
```

Then I thought of using a loop to create an object then use JSON.stringify(object).

How can I continue or redo it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a helper array for all last levels and pick the result from the first element.

This works because you take after splitting an empty string as flag for taking the last array for inserting a new object.

```js
var data = 'AA,BB\n,CC\n,,DD\n,EE',
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

data
    .split('\n')
    .forEach(s => s
        .split(',')
        .forEach((v, i) => {
            if (!v) return;
            levels[i].push({ [v]: (levels[i + 1] = []) });
        })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```